# creating a GridView on the fly with android

Tags: android, android-gridview

My problem is this.   My app will have icons on the home screen, that will be pulled from a JSON feed.  When I get my JSON feed there could be 0-10 icons that need to be displayed.  I am wondering how with strictly java i can create a gridView (assuming thats the right approach) that is centered on the screen and has a slot for each icon.  If their are more than 5 icons i want it to be two rows.  and i want there to always be even padding around the gridview so that it is essentially centered on the screen.

Is gridView the right approach? 
Can someone point me to a tutorial or tell me what i should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gridview will work.  You can tell it explicitly how many rows it should be and tell it where it should place padding.

I would use a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader.html) to get the data from the JSON feed.  Then you create a custom [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) that will define what each item in the gridview will look like.

There should be no need to create the GridView programmatically.  You can define the layout for your GridView and inflate it lazily.

Basically your loader will get and parse the data from the JSON feed, then you will pass the parsed date to your custom Adapter and call [notifyDateSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).  The only thing you need to worry about is what each element in your GridView will look like which is defined in the Adapter.  The Gridview will take care of the rest. (rows, padding, etc...)

I am not sure which API you are targeting but if its before honeycomb, you will need the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to use loaders.

Comment: I am developing for 3.1 and i have a CustomIcon class that extends tablelayout,  i want to place these custom icons in the grid..  so maybe im doing this wrong?

Comment: So you arent using any kind of adapter?

Comment: not initially, i have started a new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619394/gridview-with-customicon-class#comment12206290_9619394